# Installing libavcodec deb without root access for ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, shared-library

I need to convert FLAC files to mp3, but ffmpeg fails with

```
Encoder (codec mp3) not found for output stream #0:0
```

or with

```
Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
```

I found out that I need to install the package `libavcodec-extra`. I don't have root access on this machine, so I downloaded the .deb file, extracted its content with `ar x` and extracted content from `data.tar.xz`. This created a local `usr/lib` directory with a shared library in it.

I then added the path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/build/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

It appears that now the library is found:

```
$ ldconfig -v | grep libavcodec
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib32: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib32: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libavcodec.so.54 -> libavcodec.so.54.35.1
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
```

But ffmpeg still fails. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is to [download a static binary of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). It has support for libmp3lame. Just download, extract, and execute. No need for root or superuser.

Comment: Seems like the easiest option, thanks. I'll try it and see how it goes.